# Why is the water not colliding with an obstacle?

Tags: fluid-simulation

The water goes through the obstacle, instead of bouncing or stopping right there. Would you know how to fix this? I tried to change the "fractional" part but there is no difference.

[image]

[image]

Here is the blend file : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with the resolution of your domain: Reduce the size of the domain as much as possible, increase its *Resolution* (here I've set it to 96), and the water will come much closer to the surface of the *Effector* (see the animated gif). If you absolutely want to keep a low resolution create an invisible *Effector* that you'll put lower in the domain?

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots